# How does one calculate the look angle for non-geo satellites (i.e. LEO, HEO, etc.)

Tags: orbital-mechanics, artificial-satellite, mathematics, communication-satellite, satellite-constellation

I'm trying to find a way to calculate look angles to not just GEO satellites, but LEO, MEO, and HEO sats. The only calculator I've found myself is [here](https://deeppradhan.heliohost.org/misc/satellite-calculator.htm), which was referenced for a similar problem on Stack Exchange in regards to calculating the longitude of GEO satellites GIVEN look angles here: [Computing GEO satellite's longitude from elevation/azimuth from a given latitude/longitude?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/22850/computing-geo-satellites-longitude-from-elevation-azimuth-from-a-given-latitude)

I'm interested in two functions/formulas, both of which are calculated on that first link I posted.

1. $Az, \ El = f(earth_{lat}, \ earth_{lon}, \ sat_{lat}, \ sat_{lon}, \ altitude)$. I.e. look angle from earth station and satellite locations
2. $sat_{lat}, \ sat_{lon} = f(earth_{lat}, \ earth_{lon}, \ az, \ el, \ alt)$

So far I've started by subtracting the ECEF (geocentric) vector to the station from that of the satellite:

$v_{1} = [r*cos(earth_{lat})*cos(earth_{lon}), \ r*cos(earth_{lat})*sin(earth_{lon}), \ r*(1-f)*asin(earth_{lat})]⋅T$

$v_{2} = [R*cos(sat_{lat})*cos(sat_{lon}), R*cos(sat_{lat})*sin(sat_{lon}), R*(1-f)*sin(sat_{lat})]⋅T$

$V = v_{2}-v_{1}$

Where $r$ is the radius of Earth, $f$ is the flattening of Earth, and $R = sat_{alt} + r$.

If I'm not mistaken this should yield the vector pointing from the station to the satellite. So now I just have to transform these coordinates from ECEF to ENU (topocentric):

$t_{1} = [-sin(earth_{lon}), cos(earth_{lon}), 0]$

$t_{2} = [-sin(earth_{lat})*cos(earth_{lon}), -sin(earth_{lat})*sin(earth_{lat}), cos(earth_{lat})]$

$t_{3} = [cos(earth_{lat})*cos(earth_{lon}), cos(earth_{lat})*sin(earth_{lon}), sin(earth_{lat})]$

$T = [t_{1}, t_{2}, t_{3}]$ (ECEF to ENU transformation matrix)

$V_{ENU} = T*V$

Lastly, I calculate the azimuth and elevation:

$Az = arctan2(V_{ENU(y)}] / V_{ENU(x)}] )$
$El = arcsin(V_{ENU(z)}/ ||V_{ENU}||] )$

This keeps giving me the wrong answer, at least according to that calculator I referenced. What am I missing?

Comment: You might want to include the write/wrong answers you're working with, and code if that's what you're using.  The logic sounds correct.

Answer (score 3):

In your equation for $t_2$, the middle term ought to be
$$-\sin(earth_{LAT})*\sin(earth_{LON})$$
not
$$-\sin(earth_{LAT})*\sin(earth_{LAT})$$

Check to see if your code has the same error.  You should also try using the transpose of your T matrix, and see if that fixes it.  Beyond that, I'd ask where are you getting your satellite positions?  Might they be in ECI, rather than ECF?  Expressing what a HEO orbit looks like in ECF is a bit weird.